# Haskell List Monad State Dependance

Tags: list, haskell, state, monads

I have to write a program in Haskell that will solve some nondeterministic problem.
I think i understand List Monad in 75% so it is oblivious choice but...

(My problem is filling n x m board with ships and water i am given sums of rows and colums every part of ship has its value etd its not important right now).

I want to guard as early as possible to make algoritm effective the problem is that possibility of insertion of ship is dependant from what i am given / what i have inserted in previus moves lets call it board state and i have no idea how to pass it cuz i can't generate a new state from board alone)

My Algoritm is:
 1. Initialize First Board
 2. Generate First Row trying applying every possible insertion (i can insert sheep verticaly so i need to remember to insert other parts of sheep in lower rows)
 3. Solve the problem for smaller board (ofc after generating each 2 rows i check is everything ok)

But i have no idea how can I pass new states cuz as far as i have read about State Monad it generates new state from old state alone and this is impossible for me to do i would want to generate new state while doing operations on value).

I am sorry for my hatred towards Haskell but after few years of programing in imperative languages being forced to fight with those Monads to do things which in other languages i could write almost instantly makes me mad. (well other things in Haskell are fine for me and some of them are actually quite nice).

Comment: You don't have to write this monadically. You're perfectly capable of doing this with just good old recursion and map. (The list monad is just `mapConcat` you know)

Comment: yea i know how bind on List Monad works. And list monad do a lot of things for me like guarding.

Comment: after while of thinking it may be not a bad idea to leave Monads alone

Comment: No, there is an easy monadic solution.  Just give me a second to write it up.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Combine `StateT` with the list monad to get your desired behavior.

Here's a simple example of using the non-determinism of the list monad while still keeping a history of previous choices made:

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Trans.Class
import Control.Monad.Trans.State

fill :: StateT [Int] [] [Int]
fill = do
    history <- get
    if (length history == 3)
        then return history
        else do
            choice  <- lift [0, 1, 2]
            guard (choice `notElem` history)
            put (choice:history)
            fill
```

`fill` maintains a separate history for each path that it tries out.  If it fills up the board it returns successfully, but if the current choice overlaps with a previous choice it abandons that solution and tries a different path.

You run it using `evalStateT`, supplying an initial empty history:

```
>>> evalStateT fill []
[[2,1,0],[1,2,0],[2,0,1],[0,2,1],[1,0,2],[0,1,2]]
```

It returns a list of all possible solutions.  In this case, that just happens to be the list of all permutations in which we could have filled up the board.

Comment: Hmm i am afraid StateT is to much for me and I am not quite sure about it being solution of my problem.

Cuz i have board and i try to insert a ship(hor/ver and a water) horizontal insertion is easy to do vertical i must insert first elem of ship then pass somehow information to next row / rest of the board that i need to insert rest of parts. I need to pass information that i started building ship. After inserting ship i need to change sums of Columns and Rows. I need to change quantity of ships left to insert....

Comment: In another words i must operate on state of board and some additional row state when row is generated i have a new state. Operating on list of Touples [(Board,State)] with concatMap sems quite easier and makes me free from monads (ok except IO but i think i can deal with it). Considering i always need a state do to something and i am generating state while doing something and returning it.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood your question!  In this case you don't want to use the list monad at all.  In fact, you probably don't even want to use state either.  Why don't you just use a matrix library like `repa`?  Then you don't have to store a list of lists.  `repa` is a Haskell matrix library you can use to store and modify multi-dimensional arrays very easily.

Comment: Well return type must be list of lists so i would need to converse my answers. And anyway i must use List Monad or something that works very similiar to it. Array could be a representation of board but that does not change fact that my problem is non-deterministic so i need to use List Monad (or list with ConcatMap). Representation of board simplifies only representation.

Comment: @user2184057 What I'm trying to say is that your actual type should be something like `StateT Board [] Board`, where `Board` is a matrix/array and not a list of lists.  That way you still are using non-determinism to explore multiple ways to place ships, but you can still use a matrix to represent the board.